# How to return to switch case menu after executing method?

Tags: java, menu, switch-statement, case

I am currently writing a program that does simple arithmetic functions from a menu. Ideally I would like it to execute the method chosen from the case, and then return to the menu upon completion. Instead, when this is run it just ends the program after reaching the end of the method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String menu = ("Please choose one option from the following menu: \n"
        + "1. Calculate the sum of integers 1 to m\n"
        + "2. Calculate the factorial of a given number\n"
        + "3. Calculate the amount of odd integers in a given sequence\n"
        + "4. Display the leftmost digit of a given number\n"
        + "5. Calculate the greatest common divisor of two given integers\n"
        + "6. Quit\n");
       
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {

            System.out.println(menu);
            int selection = console.nextInt();

            switch (selection) {
                case 1:
                sumOfIntegers();
                break;

                case 2:
                factorialOfNumber();
                break;

                case 3:
                calcOddIntegers();
                break;

                case 4:
                displayLeftDigit();
                break;

                case 5:
                greatestCommonDivisor();
                break;

                case 6:
                System.out.println("Bye");
                break;
                
            }
        } while (selection != 6);
            console.close();
    }
```

I need after a menu option is selected and the method completed for it to return to the switch case menu. I have tried a do while loop from another thread but that did not work for me. I probably did something wrong and am very new to coding. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: The error that I receive is a NoSuchElementException on the line where it takes another input from the scanner.

Comment: What do you mean with _"have tried a do while loop from another thread but that did not work for me"_. You should show us this part, i think there was a problem with this.

Comment: Apologies. Updated it to reflect the attempt from the other threads info. Sorry for bad formatting as well spacing will be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a variable named `selection` that is defined inside the loop, so it is not accessible outside of it. To fix this, you should declare the variable `selection` before the loop, and then check the value of `selection` inside the loop's condition.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String menu = ("Please choose one option from the following menu: \n"
    + "1. Calculate the sum of integers 1 to m\n"
    + "2. Calculate the factorial of a given number\n"
    + "3. Calculate the amount of odd integers in a given sequence\n"
    + "4. Display the leftmost digit of a given number\n"
    + "5. Calculate the greatest common divisor of two given integers\n"
    + "6. Quit\n");

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int selection = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println(menu);
        selection = console.nextInt();

        switch (selection) {
            case 1:
                sumOfIntegers();
                break;
            case 2:
                factorialOfNumber();
                break;
            case 3:
                calcOddIntegers();
                break;
            case 4:
                displayLeftDigit();
                break;
            case 5:
                greatestCommonDivisor();
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Bye");
                break;
        }
    } while (selection != 6);
    console.close();
}
```

With this modification, the program will execute the method chosen from the case and then return to the menu upon completion.

Comment: Even with that fix, I still get a NoSuchElementException after executing the first method. Any idea what could be causing this? Would one of my methods cause this or is this the fault of my menu code?

Comment: The NoSuchElementException you are seeing is likely caused by the fact that the Scanner is being closed in the case 6 block of your switch statement. When you close the scanner, it can no longer be used to read input, which is why you are getting this exception.

To fix this, you should move the console.close() statement outside of the do-while loop, so that it is only closed after the user has selected option 6 and the program is ready to exit.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be solved with recursion.

Personally i would implement this class, (or integrate a new method):

```
    public class Cmd {

    private static final String menu = ("Please choose one option from the following menu: \n"
            + "1. Calculate the sum of integers 1 to m\n"
            + "2. Calculate the factorial of a given number\n"
            + "3. Calculate the amount of odd integers in a given sequence\n"
            + "4. Display the leftmost digit of a given number\n"
            + "5. Calculate the greatest common divisor of two given integers\n"
            + "6. Quit\n");

    private static final Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void loop() {

        System.out.println(menu);
        
        int selection = console.nextInt();



        switch (selection) {
            case 1:
                sumOfIntegers();
                break;
            case 2:
                factorialOfNumber();
                break;
            case 3:
                calcOddIntegers();
                break;
            case 4:
                displayLeftDigit();
                break;
            case 5:
                greatestCommonDivisor();
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Bye");
                console.close();
                return;
        }
        loop();
    }
}
```

This way you ensure that after each selection you return to the same state, and have the 6 as your exit condition.
Main method would look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Cmd.loop();

}
```

Bear in mind, if you dont want to implement an extra class you can simply add the loop method in the same class main is.

```
public class wopa {

    private static final String menu = ("Please choose one option from the following menu: \n"
            + "1. Calculate the sum of integers 1 to m\n"
            + "2. Calculate the factorial of a given number\n"
            + "3. Calculate the amount of odd integers in a given sequence\n"
            + "4. Display the leftmost digit of a given number\n"
            + "5. Calculate the greatest common divisor of two given integers\n"
            + "6. Quit\n");

    private static final Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loop();
    }

    public static void loop() {

        System.out.println(menu);

        int selection = console.nextInt();

        switch (selection) {
            case 1:
                sumOfIntegers();
                break;
            case 2:
                factorialOfNumber();
                break;
            case 3:
                calcOddIntegers();
                break;
            case 4:
                displayLeftDigit();
                break;
            case 5:
                greatestCommonDivisor();
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Bye");
                console.close();
                return;
        }
        loop();
    }
}
```

And if you want to keep the same schema you had. You can always add the loop method inside main method, and instead of using recursion englobe it in a while(true) (don't really like this option)

Comment: I think this is what I’m looking for. Turns out my error was actually caused by me closing my scanner in the other methods and inadvertently closing the system.in input stream as well. This implementation is much less sloppy though than me leaving my scanners open.

Comment: Glad it helps, ii would also consider moving the selection to a class attribute, and just modify it inside the loop method. 
Lmk if you need help with anything else, or implementing this in your current code!